What connector is this? (1.2 mm pitch pad array)
I have a mystery board which has 196 pads that are meant to connect to something.

The pads are arranged in four staggered rows of 49 (4 × 49 = 196). The pitch is 1.20 mm exactly. I double-checked, it’s metric, and it’s not 1.27 mm aka 0.05".
This is apparently meant to connect to another board just by pressing this board down on it (both boards parallel, with some alignment holes/pins). So what is the connector on the other board?
My first thought was pogo pin strips — these come in multiple rows sometimes, and I’ve seen 1.27 mm pitch (common) as well as 1.0 mm and 1.5 mm.  But it seems they’re not made staggered, and I couldn’t find anyone who makes a 1.20 mm version.
I searched a bit and this looks like what would be called an “open pin-field array”. Samtec makes these, and some are staggered rows — but none are 1.20 mm (and also need connectors on both sides).
So, I just can’t figure it out.
I suppose it could just be a board populated with individual pogo pins in though holes, but the manufacturing on that would be really hard. Can anyone help figure this out?
I hope this helps someone in the future who wants to make two boards with a large number of connectors ;)
P.S. This doesn’t carry high-speed signals — although it might well be a high speed connector because the pitch is so small. The other mating side is probably rated for a fairly high number of cycles (thousands).

I wouldn't think this would be rated for thousands of cycles. If you want a connector to endure that much, you need to at least ensure the contacts are self-wiping (which there's no practical way to do with this pad layout), and you definitely don't want to tin-plate them--you need a more corrosion-resistant plating, like hard gold.

@Hearth You're right!  I should have been more specific.  From what I know of the device, the other side (which I don't have) would be rated for a large number of cycles. This side isn't ;)

maybe it is not a connector per se ... could be a test point array ... please post a picture of the whole board

@jsotola You mean a set of individual pogo pins like the standard P50 size? https://midnorthcoastcomponents.com/product-category/pogo-pins/  I thought about it, they would fit, but assembling a board with that many would be hell... It just seemed more likely this is a strip, like this https://www.mill-max.com/products/spring-loaded/pogo-pin-header-strip/855/10-001101

@jsotola I'm sorry, I can't post the whole board but I can answer anything you want to know about it. These pads are along one edge, and they're definitely used in service not just during test. It seems the idea was to make something that functions like a mezzanine connector, but where one side of it can be made of pads only. The other side is??

have a look at a picture in this post ... https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/717378/what-is-the-best-way-to-retrofit-a-connection-between-a-circuit-board-and-its-ca

@jsotola that's wild! Is the Honda board wirebonded or soldered? (question says soldered but idk how one would even manufacture that)  I think in this case it may be springs if not pogo pins, because - it's four rows!  even if it were possible to solder to the outside row, there's no way to do that for four rows
