What is the best way to retrofit a connection between a circuit board and its case (housing)?
This is a very specific well defined question, imho, but it's also likely to be that I can do anything better. This strikes me as amazingly bad engineering.
Hondas and Accuras all have a problem with the VSA Unit (also sometimes called the ABS module) which is a sealed unit (I opened mine with a oscillating multitool and a plastic-cutting blade.). This unit has faulty connections from the circuit board to the case. The OEM made connectivity with very small soldered uncoated rigid conductive solid leads. You can see a picture here,
Picture taken from the video at 2007 Honda Civic si No Communication with Gauge Control Module Figured Out

All of these units go bad because the leads are subject to heat and vibration and eventually they just wear off sometimes falling out and shorting inside the unit. It's a very hot item for component level repair and multiple sellers on eBay perform it.
My question is as to what is the best way to reasonably solve this issue. Is there a reasonable way to replace the leads with a ribbon that will provide for some flex? Is there a better way to do this then to use the same rigid solid-core leads the way the OEM did?

If you also have this issue and in the USA I suggest filing a report with NHTSA

As both an EE and a Honda driver...this is horrifying.

@evildemonic yeah, this is some insanely bad EE from my perspective but I'm an idiot. BTW, this module is $1500 new, which is crazzzyy https://www.hondapartsnow.com/oem-honda-abs_control_module.html AND replacing it on a Honda (unlike an Accord) requires you to issue the ABS pump command over a bidirectional OBDII device. So you're looking at $3000 for dealer repair and installation. Or if you do it all yourself (as I'm doing) you need a special $200 device for ABS Pump Activation at the very least. It's also very hard to diagnose. No OBDII code, all dash lights come on.

I fear that whatever solution we come up with will be even reliable than the original solution because of the inconsistency of human manufacturing compared to machine manufacturing.

From the video it looks like the wires break right at the weld to the case terminals where the wire is squished down giving a stress riser-- and maybe metallurgically changed (embrittled? due to the heat of welding). The weld does not fail, the wire does.

Once that end is broken the wire is flopping around and will eventually break somewhere else.
A bit curious it does not fail sometimes at the PCB. Maybe the spot weld energy is less for that bond so there is less necking.
Nasty application.. it's mounted above the wheel well where there is lots of vibration and has the rigid brake lines bolted to it and looks fairly hefty so there is going to be relative motion between the PCB and case.
I suppose you could run a bead of electronic-grade (only) RTV silicone over the wire bonds (or silicone conformal coating), but that would make it pretty much unrepairable later and opening it carries multiple risks and might not help (could conceivably hurt).

That's a really good idea with the RTV silicon after I validate the welds I may have to do that. That's a low-tech solution that accomplishes what I want. Cool answer. Never thought of that of silicon to eliminate wire stress.

what kind of wires would you suggest I use to replace missing wires?

I think I'd try AWG 30 wire wrap wire (stripped of the Kynar insulation) because that's what I have on hand. But it might be too big.

would you go copper, steel, stainless?

Copper to be easily solderable with benign fluxes.

Specifically, fine gauge single-strand plated wire, not bare copper.  For some reason small rolls of that stuff are $$$ so for a few pieces it's easier to strip some wire. You could strip stranded wire and use single strands. For example, the coarsest typical stranding of AWG 24 wire is 7/32 so each strand is 32 gauge or about 0.2mm (8 mils) diameter.

What about something like this, https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B07CJL9NTT

Not stainless. Stainless wire will be very difficult to join to the existing parts. Possibly too big in diameter too.

Do you have an amazon link, I can't find any of this?

Google AWG 24 stranded wire, for example. Some of it is much finer than others. But seriously you don't need more than a few cm and just about any defunct electronic product will have some wire in it that can easily be stripped and the strands tried. You should not have to buy anything.

Yeah, I can't even find AWG 24 stranded steel wire. This stuff is almost impossible to find.

followup https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/720810/15877

Here's  one of many examples, on amazon.com. The individual strands are 0.16mm (11 of them), you'd have to check to see if that was suitable. But I bet you don't have to buy anything. Steel is not much better than SS, it doesn't solder with normal electronic-grade solder and flux, only with very corrosive fluxes.

Ohhh, ok you did say to use tinned copper, awesome! That's easy to come by. I thought you said no to tinned copper and no to stainless. I already bought this, https://www.amazon.com/dp/B006C4CYRK when I read your post the first time, I seems to be a perfect match then.

Electrically fine. Hopefully it's not too big.

I ended up giving up on it. I can't get anything to work with device. Nothing will stick to those steel terminals in it.

Nothing to it. Remove the existing sitff connections and replace them with short lengths of high strand count Teflon insulated hook-up wire.

This, and then epoxy or  silicone conformal coat for additional strain relief.
