What concerns are there with soldering stainless steel cable on electronics?
This is a follow up to this question.

I have a case where a circuit board is soldered to the housing using steel cable. I can't find high-gauge non-stainless steel cable. One of the comments said this when I asked about making the solder joints stainless steel.

Not stainless. Stainless wire will be very difficult to join to the existing parts. Possibly too big in diameter too. –

Why would stainless steel be difficult to join? How is it more difficult than steel that's not stainless? If I use flux, wouldn't it function just like any other steel cable? What precautions should I take if I wanted to proceed?

Can you use a crimp terminal for the electrical connection?

@DaveTweed nope, not in my case see the question linked at the top if you want to know more -- or have any clever ideas.

To add insult to the injury, stainless steel is rather poor electrical conductor.

@fraxinus and brittle. Copper, silver or gold would be far more malleable.

My worktop used to be a plate of stainless. Trust me, it won't take solder. Crimping stainless is a common thing (see every sailboat) and a crimped strop you can bolt to a pad will be easy to source.

Non-stainless steel cable?  try picture wire, the zinc plated stuff should solder easily.

It is possible to solder to stainless steel. The problem is that the flux must be a very strong acid, and if after completing your soldering you do not remove all remnant traces of the acid flux, you will have problems with the parts to which you solder the stainless steel. Another problem is that 'stainless steel' is a family of products, some of which require different acid fluxes.

Some metals are much more compatible with solder than other metals. Stainless steel is one of those metals that's very incompatible with solder--fluxes (even many of the really aggressive ones--it may be possible using hydrochloric acid as a flux, for instance, but that would cause problems with the PCB) can't get through the layer of chromium oxides that make the steel stainless in the first place--chromium plating is how they make sure solder doesn't stick to the wrong parts of your soldering iron!
For reference, some metals by solderability:
Easily solderable:

copper
tin
lead
gold
silver
palladium
platinum
zinc
most alloys of the above
some glasses, too

Solderable with lots of flux:

nickel
cupronickel
iron

Solderable with specialty fluxes, solders, and/or techniques:

aluminum
silicon
some steels

Not solderable:

chromium
tungsten
titanium
stainless (high-chromium) steels
chromel (a component of type-K thermocouples, so quite common)
alumel (the other part of type-K thermocouples)
nichrome

Other problems with soldering:

bismuth (alloys with common tin-lead solders to form a low-melting, very brittle intermetallic phase. Can be soldered with lead-free solders.
indium (melts before the solder does, unless using unusual solders)
gallium (same problem as indium)


Some entries in the "not solderable" section may well be amenable to brazing, which is the same process as soldering but done at much higher temperatures. You may have some success attempting to braze stainless steel, but the temperatures involved would destroy a PCB.

Nice list. +1 Thin gold wire dissolves into solder pretty quickly too, and the dissolved gold forms a brittle intermetallic with tin.

@SpehroPefhany I knew there were problems with Au-Al intermetallics, but I'd never heard of trouble with Au-Sn ones. Something to look into!

It was a problem with boards that have thick gold plating, like in the old days (and sometimes today for high-quality contact fingers). Nowadays the ENIG gold is so thin that it doesn't affect the metallurgical properties when it disappears into the melt.

I've never heard of soldering silicon? AFAIK, all the "nots" are in the specialty flux category. Metals love to stick together, just a matter of getting them to touch. Also iron is in the "lots of flux" category; if it's clean, it's not particularly hard with regular rosin.

Yup. Modern soldering iron tips are iron-plated and tinned.

@TimWilliams It's common for die attach; the solder used for it is a gold-silicon alloy that is slightly gold-rich from eutectic (so that the silicon dissolving into it can make it eutectic). Though that made me realize that I should move the silicon entry to specialty solders.

That's more of a brazing process, but it's also done on top of metallization, typically Ti, Ni and Au in order.  Sn10Pb90 is also commonly used for that, AFAIK.

This is a good overall answer but maybe a bit to negative on some of the "not solderable". Many of those are solderable with exactly the right flux, and in particular most grades of stainless are not that bad using a phosphoric acid flux.

of course every list of metals must include gallium at some point. I don't think anyone is trying to solder gallium. But can I solder to mercury?

Stainless steel is easy to solder with a phosphoric acid flux. The poor thermal conductivity helps also.
Maybe tin the SS, remove flux residue, and then try conventional soldering.

A useful link given by the vendors of this. No experience with it whatsoever.

Stainless can be soldered, but a speciality flux is needed.
Flux-core solders are available for stainless steel,  eg Loctite ALU.
The solder metal is a regular tin-lead or or lead-free formulation, the flux however is not safe for electronics work, so use the solder to tin the stainless steel. wash the flux residue off and then use regular solder to join the tinned stainless steel to the circuit.

The whole issue stems from the connection being too rigid. Using steel for electrical connections is a bit silly due to higher resistance relative to copper when you can just use normal stranded copper wire.
For a permanent repair, PTFE-insulated high flex (high strand count) copper hook-up wire will do the job very well. You’ll cut-and-strip identical wires in required quantity in advance. Then cut each original connection off and solder the replacement wire in its place. I have done this multiple times in different electronic modules that had similarly moronic design.
The main reason it may be more economical to have a repair shop do this job is that the wire may need to be custom ordered on a larger spool and has to be amortized over several repairs to make financial sense. If you can’t find suitable hook-up wire from mainstream dealers, then eBay may be the next best choice - buy old stock, most likely military/aerospace wire.
